# повторяющиеся запросы на сервер за шрифтами из стилей в SVG (@font-face)

Tags: html, css, svg, шрифты, оптимизация-сайтов

Друзья, вопрос такой: На сайте имеются SVG содержащие текст, к ним прикрепляются шрифты внутри `<defs><style>` с помощью

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'PTSans-Regular'; 
    src: url('../../fonts/ptsans-regular.ttf');
    }
```

Шрифты лежат на сервере в папке `fonts/font.ott`

Проблема в том, что при каждом вызове @font-face идёт обращение на сервер за шрифтом(это видно в консоли) и если у нас 10 svg, то это 10 обращений.
как этого избежать?
Может можно както 1 раз загрузить шрифты к пользователю, а потом использовать их из кэша браузера через локальный доступ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Настроить кеширование

Comment: @AlexeyTen подскажите, куда копать

Comment: Где-то в вашем веб-сервере

Comment: [Очевидно это может помочь](https://yandex.kz/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.internet-technologies.ru%2Farticles%2Fkesh-brauzera.html&d=1)

Comment: @MaximLensky то есть, другими словами, я хочу один раз скачивать шрифт при вызове font-face, а если он требуется в дальнейшем, к примеру, в другом файле svg, чтобы использовался уже загруженный ранее шрифт. Кэширование поможет в этом?

Comment: по идее кэширование решается браузером но ссылка выше говорит о принудительном включении

Comment: @MaximLensky проблема немного в другом, я сейчас говорю о первой загрузке сайта, не о последующих. Каждый запрос font-face src: url('....'); заново загружает уже загруженный шрифт в предыдущем svg, svg подключаю как object. Как сказать другим svg, что шрифт уже был скачан ранее предыдущим svg-файлом и заставить их использовать этот шрифт?